# Auth Error code: 47 when sign up via email in Flutter Web and Web App

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm migrating a Flutter Web app (and **also** a Web App without Flutter) to Identity Platform following [the example in the official GitHub repo](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example).

The SignUp using the google provider is working fine, but registration via email is not working throwing an 503 http error and logging an error with no useful information (at least to me) in the Logs Explorer. I'm not able to find the way to restore the email SignUp.

Tried starting a project from scratch with the same result.

Next is the error captured by the Logs Explorer:

```json
{
  "insertId": "-6nlbdid1yva",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "status": {
      "code": 13,
      "message": "Error code: 47"
    },
    "methodName": "google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignUp",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.identitytoolkit.logging.RequestLog",
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)"
    },
    "request": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.SignUpRequest",
      "email": "XXXXXXXX@XXXXX.com"
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "identitytoolkit_project",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "my-project-id"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-05-06T17:34:25.415Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/my-project-id/logs/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com%2Frequests",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-05-06T17:34:26.070942970Z"
}
```

Version:

```
Flutter 3.7.12 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4d9e56e694 (3 weeks ago) • 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
Engine • revision 1a65d409c7
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1


environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'
  flutter: ">=3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

#  Firebase dependencies
  firebase_core: ^2.11.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.6.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.1.2
  firebase_messaging: ^14.5.0

#  Auth
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of hours looking for the problem, I found on what is related.

There is a function that runs when the signup is triggered and it is failing when the auth provider is the emaol/password

BTW, the log and error message that the platform trigger is completely useless.